# Bing Maps on IE 11 browser, The mouse click event is only working when we have compatibility mode on

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bing-maps

I am using Ajax to call the C# from Javascript and load the data from database.

I have used following article to show the pushpins and there infoboxes.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rbrundritt/archive/2013/11/08/multiple-pushpins-and-infoboxes-in-bing-maps-v7.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

My code works great on IE 11 , when I have compatibility mode on,

but when compatibility mode is off, the mouse click event is not being received by the Javascript function.

I tried using Chrome and I had the same issue.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Maps.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BingMaps.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyMaps.secure.BingMaps" %>
```

....

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"
   EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server">
      </asp:Literal>
```

var map = null, infobox, dataLayer;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            GetMap();

```
    });
    function GetMap() {
        // Initialize the map
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("MapHolder"),
                   { credentials: "lincensekey", zoom: 2 });

        dataLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        map.entities.push(dataLayer);

        var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);

        infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { visible: false, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 20) });
        infoboxLayer.push(infobox);
        PageMethods.GetLocations(RequestCompletedCallback, RequestFailedCallback);

    }

    function AddData(MapPoints) {


        for (var i = 0, len = MapPoints.length; i < len; ++i)
        {
            var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(parseFloat(MapPoints[i].lat),parseFloat(MapPoints[i].lon))
                , {
                        icon: MapPoints[i].group,
                        height: 50, width: 60, text: MapPoints[i].city
                    });
            pushpin.Title = MapPoints[i].name;
            pushpin.description = MapPoints[i].desc;
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'click', displayInfobox);
            dataLayer.push(pushpin);
        }
    }

    function displayInfobox(e) {
        if (e.targetType == 'pushpin') {
            infobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
            infobox.setOptions({ visible: true, title: e.target.Title, description: e.target.description });
        }
    }

    function RequestCompletedCallback(result) {
        result = eval(result);
        AddData(result);
    }

    function RequestFailedCallback(error) {
        var stackTrace = error.get_stackTrace();
        var message = error.get_message();
        var statusCode = error.get_statusCode();
        var exceptionType = error.get_exceptionType();
        var timedout = error.get_timedOut();

        alert("Stack Trace: " + stackTrace + "<br/>" +
            "Service Error: " + message + "<br/>" +
            "Status Code: " + statusCode + "<br/>" +
            "Exception Type: " + exceptionType + "<br/>" +
            "Timedout: " + timedout);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The pointer events in the SVG standard are implemented slightly differently in IE 11, chrome and firefox with respect to previous versions.

I had to  set the container div with pointer-events:none, to receive the mouse events.

```
<div class="divRow" style="pointer-events: none;">
                <div id="MapHolder" style="width:900px; height:540px;display:block; margin-left:5px;top:2px; ">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I did some more work on it and nailed it down to following 

We see the problem with mouse events on IE 11, 

only if the Map holding div is within the <asp:Content tag.

If it is outside the 

    <asp:Content

 tag, it works fine.